# Terraform init connection time outs searching for provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I try to do a terraform init and it fails. This used to work before, not sure what changed. Any ideas on this please?

I am able to curl the same url and it works fine.

tf version: 1.1.5
aws version: 4.4.0

````
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 4.4.0"...
2022-08-10T10:05:00.750-0700 [DEBUG] Service discovery for registry.terraform.io at https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
2022-08-10T10:05:11.191-0700 [DEBUG] GET https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions
2022-08-10T10:05:21.196-0700 [ERROR] GET https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions request failed: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2022-08-10T10:05:21.196-0700 [DEBUG] GET https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions: retrying in 1s (1 left)
2022-08-10T10:05:22.198-0700 [INFO]  Previous request to the remote registry failed, attempting retry.
2022-08-10T10:05:32.199-0700 [ERROR] GET https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions request failed: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: the
│ request failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/v1/providers/hashicorp/aws/versions": net/http: request canceled
│ while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)```
````

Comment: Maybe there is a temporary downtime, maybe you have weird network settings. Does it work on other machines, when did it last work, when did it first stop working?

Comment: It depends on where you are doing the `curl` & `terraform init`. If both are run from the same machine, you have something weird happening with `.terraform` directory. If not, there could be network devices in between intercepting the traffic.

Comment: When you use Curl, does it seem like the request takes a long time? On a Unix system you could run `time curl ...` to see approximately how long that request is taking. I'm wondering if Curl has a more generous timeout than Terraform does. If you try this, I'd suggest also updating your question to include the exact command you ran and the full output it produced, so it's easier to compare that with what Terraform is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs everyone.

I found the issue. I had to set the dns of my Mac to 8.8.8.8

I don’t know how/why but that worked.

Answer (score 0):

So the question is, why this is happening on some servers, and not on others ?
and why the above's answer on changing the DNS works ? because when you changed your local DNS - you changed the bad resolver that you had - and replaced it with a different one.

So in order to solve this issue, you first need to review your existing DNS entries.

In my case, I had a lab DNSs in a production server. removing them - solved my issue ( they were added with Ansible )

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

And I would start debugging with each line ( comment some out ) until you find out the DNS that is causing the issue.